# How to upload and save a video in landscape mode

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, browser, orientation

I'm trying to upload/save a taken video(if shot in portrait mode) in landscape mode. Using the UIImagePickerController, According to these questions:

[video orientation UIImagePickerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7879633/video-orientation-uiimagepickercontroller/)

[How can I set the UIImagePickerController orientation for video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193451/how-can-i-set-the-uiimagepickercontroller-orientation-for-video)

These questions(and many others) explain how to determine if the video is shot in portrait orientation but I cannot find a answer to how a video can actually be uploaded and saved(to a server) in an orientation that when played on a media device the video isn't horizontal and weird looking. Can we come to conclusion here for everyone who has looked into this and see if/how this can be done?