# Pick only landscape video / image from photo library

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

Is there a way to pick only landscape orientation videos from library in objective C ? Does the mediaTypes property has a way to pick only those vides that were recorded in landscape mode? Is there a way to show only landscape recorded videos from library in popOver? Or is there any workaround? This [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiimagepickercontroller_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/mediaTypes) does not meet my requirement.

```
UIImagePickerController *mediaUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
mediaUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

mediaUI.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil]; //Any way to pick only landscape videos? Or is there any workaround?
mediaUI.allowsEditing = YES;
mediaUI.delegate = self;
self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                                              initWithContentViewController:mediaUI];

self.popoverController.delegate = self;

[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(250, self.videoMenuView.frame.origin.y-10, 40, 40) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
```

Comment: calculate the width and height, if Width > height, obvioulsly the image is in landscape mode

Comment: @DebanjanChakraborty How do I use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627940/how-to-detect-iphone-sdk-if-a-video-file-was-recorded-in-portrait-orientation in my code?

Comment: mediaUI.delegate = self; Check if the UIImagePickerDelegate callback for didFinishPicking comes or not

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, but is there anyway to show only landscape recorded videos in the photo library? We calculate it only after we finish picking media and not before it loads in the popOver.

Comment: So, you need to access your gallery via AssetLibrary, get the images, filter via the condition and save in an array. In that case You won't be using UIImagePicker in UIPopOver, probably a UITableView or a UICollectionView to represent those selected elements. Obviously, you need to that before the popObver is opened