# CMSampleBuffer automatically rotate every time

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

Here I try to select video from photo library and read it frame by frame as a `samplebuffer` so that I can crop or rotate later.but the problem is `CMSampleBuffer` by default rotated.The variables are I use for initialization is

```
 var asset:AVAsset!     //load asset from url
 var assetReader:AVAssetReader!   
 var assetVideoOutput: AVAssetReaderTrackOutput!  // add assetreader for video
 var assetAudioOutput: AVAssetReaderTrackOutput!  // add assetreader for audio
 var readQueue: DispatchQueue!
```

the settings of previous variables looks like this.

```
func resetRendering() {

    do{
        assetReader = try! AVAssetReader(asset: asset)
    }catch {
        print(error)
    }

    var tracks = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)
    var track : AVAssetTrack!
    if tracks.count > 0 {
        track = tracks[0]
    }

    let decompressionvideoSettings:[String:Any] = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]

    assetVideoOutput = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(track: track, outputSettings: decompressionvideoSettings)

    tracks = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .audio)
    if tracks.count > 0 {
        track = tracks[0]
    }

    let audioReadSettings = [AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatLinearPCM]
    assetAudioOutput = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(track: track, outputSettings: audioReadSettings)

    if (assetAudioOutput.responds(to: #selector(getter: AVAssetReaderOutput.alwaysCopiesSampleData))) {
        assetAudioOutput.alwaysCopiesSampleData = false
    }
    if assetReader.canAdd(assetAudioOutput) {
        assetReader.add(assetAudioOutput)
    }

    if (assetVideoOutput.responds(to: #selector(getter: AVAssetReaderOutput.alwaysCopiesSampleData))) {
        assetVideoOutput.alwaysCopiesSampleData = false
    }
    if assetReader.canAdd(assetVideoOutput) {
        assetReader.add(assetVideoOutput)
    }

}
```

now when I try to read video frame by frame and convert into image it automatically rotate frame in 90 degrees.the conversion extention from `samplebuffer` to `uiimage` looks like this

```
extension CMSampleBuffer {
    var uiImage: UIImage? {
        guard let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(self) else { return nil }

        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
        let baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer)
        let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer)
        let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer)
        let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer)
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipFirst.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Little.rawValue)
        guard let context = CGContext(data: baseAddress,
                                      width: width,
                                      height: height,
                                      bitsPerComponent: 8,
                                      bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow,
                                      space: colorSpace,
                                      bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue) else { return nil }
        guard let cgImage = context.makeImage() else { return nil }

        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0));

        return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
    }
}
```

resulted photo is

[image]

and actual photo is this one

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

CGImage doesn't hold orientation property. So you have to manually set when you convert to UIImage. We get orientation from video track and set it to UIImage.

Below answer's right/left or up/down might be opposite. Pls try and check.

```
//pls get orientation property outside of image processing to avoid redundancy
let videoTrack = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video).first!
let videoSize = videoTrack.naturalSize
let transform = videoTrack.preferredTransform

var orientation = UIImage.Orientation.right
switch (transform.tx, transform.ty) {
case (0, 0): orientation = UIImage.Orientation.up
case (videoSize.width, videoSize.height): UIImage.Orientation.right
case (0, videoSize.width): UIImage.Orientation.left
default: orientation = UIImage.Orientation.down
}


// then set orientation in image processing such as captureOutput
let uiImage = UIImage.init(cgImage: cgImage, scale: 1.0, orientation: orientation)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Some video it gives proper orientation but some are not.So if I rotate every one then it may not help me for some video.

Comment: Catch the orientation for each video and set proper one. As cgImage forgets orientation data, we get it from video track and set at UIImage.init(: : :). Pls refer to cleverbit's answer on this post for how you get orientation data. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627940/how-to-detect-if-a-video-file-was-recorded-in-portrait-orientation-or-landscape